# How are large detailed models created?

Tags: modeling, 3dsmax

I am new to modeling and I have always been wondering how large detailed models are made. For example, i have used an app that features the entire human body where i can select different parts up to blood vessels and bones. Is it created in one giant model or does it consist of small parts and then somehow we link them together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed tomography (CT) data of a real man for this purpose. CT contains information about all internal organs, vessels and bones, as well as about skin surface.

You can easily detect skin and bone surfaces using different threshold segmentation. If the quality of CT is quite good you can also detect organes, but then you will need to spend some time to split them and clean noises. If you need to show the vessels structure, you use CT with a contrast agent in the blood and the blood will be also easily detected with a threshold method.

So, you can open a file, extract some isosurfaces at different thresholds (using Seg3D app for example). To remove noise, split and smooth objects you can use Geomagic Studio software. Then you can use these surfaces to construct different anatomical objects, setup materials, put textures and in any 3D program.

Using such way it is possible to obtain a REALY DETAILED and anatomicaly correct model of a human with all small bones and vessels.

If you need the possibility to show/hide some objects in your application, you just add some labels into names of the segmented objects and then display only the objects that matches these labels.

Answer (score 0):

If we talking about the mesh in example Autodesk 3D Max.

if you not have created a mesh-model by using nurbs. 
Read about nurbs here: 
[Nurbs models](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-FD120DDE-E8BE-4DB9-A2CA-62069059B4FF-htm.html)

If you have created your mesh-model with polygons you can apply mesh smooth and other modifiers that makes the model looks good.

There are very many different ways make a model looks realistic.
You can make a model that have very low polygon count.
then you put the mesh model in example:

**Mudbox**
**Zbrush**

You can in these programs apply a kind of meshsmooth on the parts you need to make a certain pattern for example a "ear" or the whole mesh.

You can also make something looks very detailed in the material example,
Displacement mapping or bump etc.

I hope this will give you a hint of how you can make it.